# SQL query with capitalized table name returns empty result set on Linux, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu

```
SELECT * FROM Country
```

returns empty result set, but

```
SELECT * FROM country
```

returns valid data

It happens on Linux Ubuntu, mysql version 5.6.19.
On Windows everything is working ok.

Comment: Read here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html.  Case sensitivity in table names is related to the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system.  And Linux is typically case sensitive.

Comment: So, why doesn't mysql throw an error 'Table country doesn't exist'?

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko You are right, it should throw error for table not existing in first place if really  being case sensitive is the issue here. Then probably, just out of curiosity, check if there is another table , in this case Country which is with no records .

Comment: Did you check information_schema? Please also try SELECT * FROM `Country` and SELECT * FROM `country`

Comment: "throw error" -- What client are you using?  Do you have an empty table called "Country"?  It is not an error to have an empty result set; that is a feature.

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko . . . That is really interesting.  The metadata in the database can be case insensitive when the underlying OS imposes case sensitivity on tables and databases.  That is probably why it is not throwing error.